# Create my own iphone Photolibrary

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios5

I want to create my own photolibrary that takes images from my library and save them into my library and ask whether to dekete or not..Will appreciate any help

Regards

Ghaus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well you could let the user select which images to import using the UIImagePickerControl. See this excellent post for details 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282830/uiimagepickercontroller-uiimage-memory-and-more

Afterwards save/load the image to your own app with something like this

```
- (void)saveImage: (UIImage*)image
{
    if (image != nil)
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                      NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
                       [NSString stringWithString: @"test.png"] ];
        NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    }
}



- (UIImage*)loadImage
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                      NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
                      [NSString stringWithString: @"test.png"] ];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Thnx for the anwser...really helpful

Answer (score -2):

add this :

```
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{


    if ([self isPad]) {

        if(picker.sourceType==UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary)
        {

            [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

        }
        else
        {
            [picker  dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            [picker release];

        }

    }   
    else
    {

        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
    }

}

-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) picker     didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo :(NSDictionary *)info

{   
    UIImage *imageToScale=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    flagImageSelected=YES;
    /*Set Image on the Btn with Image Insets.*/    
    //Image Insets TOP, LEFT, BOTTOM, RIGHT
    if([self isPad])
    {
        [btnImage setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(31.0,33.0,36,36.0)];

        //imageToScale =[imageToScale scale:CGSizeMake(530, 546)];
        imageToScale=[imageToScale scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(530, 546)];  


    }
    else
    {
        [btnImage setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(13.0,13.0,14.0,14.0)];
        imageToScale=[imageToScale scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(300, 300)];  

    }

    [btnImage setImage:imageToScale forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 



    if ([self isPad]) {

        if(picker.sourceType==UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary)
        {

            [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

        }
        else
        {
            [picker  dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            [picker release];

        }

    }   
    else
    {
        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        //[picker release];
    }
}
-(NSString *) getImagePath{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSError *error;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error]; 
    return documentsDirectory;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIActionSheet *action = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select and capture photos in LANDSCAPE mode for best results" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Photo Library",@"Capture", nil];
    [action showInView:self.view];
    [action release];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        if ([self isPad])
        {    
            UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; 
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary; 
            picker.delegate = self;    
            NSLog(@"POP OVER CONTROLLER Retain Count Before %d",[popoverController retainCount]);

            if (popoverController) popoverController = nil;
            popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];

            [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(btnImage.frame.origin.x, btnImage.frame.origin.y, btnImage.frame.size.width, btnImage.frame.size.height) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
            NSLog(@"POP OVER CONTROLLER Retain Count Before %d",[popoverController retainCount]);

            [picker release];
        }
        else 
        {
            if(ipc)
            {
                ipc=nil;
                [ipc release];
            }
            ipc=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            ipc.delegate=self;

            ipc.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            [self presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES];
        }        
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        {
            if(ipc)
            {
                [ipc release];
                ipc=nil;
            }
            ipc=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            ipc.delegate=self;
            ipc.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

            [self presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES];
        }
        else
        {  
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"winEaux" message:@"Camera capture is not supported in this device" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) retainCount is useless.  (2) This code has a number of serious bugs indicating that the author of the code copy/pasted it together without thinking through what each line does.  (3) posting code without an explanation or context isn't terribly helpful (unless it is short and "just works").